# Why I got non-numeric argument to binary operator with nls?

Tags: r

I have two vectors (example):

```
x=c(100,98,60,30,28,30,20,10)
y=c(10,9.8,5,3,2,3.4,2.8,1)
```

I would like to fit them using this function:

and get the fitting parameters  `a b c d`
      [image]

I used this:

```
     m<-nls(x~a/1+e^(-b*(y-c))  + d)
```

but I got this error:

```
     Error in y - c : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x and y are reversed and e^(...) should be exp(...).  Also I found that setting d to 0 helped.

```
d <- 0  # fix d at 0
st <- list(a = mean(y), b = 1/sd(x), c = mean(x))
fm <- nls(y ~ a/(1+exp(-b*(x-c))) + d, start = st)
fm
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a/(1 + exp(-b * (x - c)))
   data: parent.frame()
       a        b        c 
19.96517  0.02623 99.73842 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.82

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.023e-06
```

Plotting this it seems to be a good fit visually:

```
plot(y ~ x)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that `c` is considered as the `combine` operator. Change that to another symbol (`c1` for instance). Of course you would also ened to specify meaningful starting paramaters, but I guess that was not your question.

Comment: i change c to c1 but i got this: Error in .getE2(e2) : 
  use 1, 2, or 4 numbers in arithmetic operations with an Extent

Comment: Difficult to test, because as said you need to provide meaningful start values. If I try: `m<-nls(x~a/(1+exp(-b*(y-c1))) + d, start = c(a=1, b=1, c1=1, d=1))` I get "only" ther error "singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates"

Comment: Also note that you want `exp()` and not `e^` and you missed some brackets in the denominator.